# How can I get get elements by array of keys from a collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a collection (for example with 10 elements), I want to do make out another collection of elements of just two elements with ids of 5 and 6. Something like that:

```
$newCollection = $collection->get([5,6]);
```

$collection is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`.
But of course I get error:

> The first argument should be either a string or an integer

I know I can make it with cycle or closures, I just wandering if there is more elegant way. Can not find such thing in the documentation. This is for laravel 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Collection::only.

For example:

`$collection->only([5, 6]);`

Note that it looks at the attribute primary key to know which key to work against. For example, if returning a database collection, `$collection->primaryKey` will most likely be 'id'.

Answer (score 1):

Using a filter perhaps, assuming these are id values:

```
$idList = [5,6];
$newCollection = collection->filter(
    function($value) use ($idList) {
        if (in_array(value->id, $idList) {
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Yes, this works just fine, but I need this pretty often, so I am quite sure there has to be more elegant way..

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use `whereIn()`

```
$newCollection = $collection->whereIn('id', [5, 6])->get();
```

**OR**

Directly using eloquent model:

```
$newCollection = Collection::whereIn('id', [5, 6])->get();
```

Comment: Nope..Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereIn()

Comment: You are using Eloquent?

Comment: @Blum and the $collection is object of what? please specify

Comment: Sorry, $collection is an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection. Question updated.

Comment: Here is the documentation for laravel query builder, search for "Using Where In With An Array" - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Comment: This is for query builder. This is not my case.

Comment: Then the array filter is the best way to do this.